# How to load and save documents in MS word 2010 using streams

Tags: c#, ms-office

I am looking for a way to use Microsoft Word, and possibly Excel, in a such a way that the documents are loaded from and saved to a SQL Server database through stored procedures. My thinking is that it should be possible to instantiate a word document through a stream, but I haven't found any methods or interfaces supporting this.

In delphi 7, back in the days, I managed to do this using OLE containers since they have stream support. It was then just a matter of creating a stream with the correct OLE header and footer and in between writing the document object. It seems that OLE is totally dead nowadays though, so that is probably not an option now.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and office 2010.

Comment: So after you get stream from SQL server, do you want to display it or just do something else so far?

Comment: I want to open it with word, preferably without resorting to saving it as a temp file first. That I know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to store documents in SQL Server you might want to see [SQL Server Filestream](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Realizing that it is impossible to disable file handling in word I've changed focus. the idea now is to replace the standard open and save dialogs with my own, custom ones. For save this was easy, just adding an event handler for DocumentBeforeSave. I haven't found anything similar for the opening of documents. Any ideas anyone?